# I need to be able to 'rotate' a list thats in a 'square' looking formation into a diamond shape python

Tags: python, list, wordsearch

I am creating a word search solver and need a way to rotate the word search, which is in a list, so the left corner is the 'top' and the bottom right is at the 'bottom'

I have this:

```
 Puzzle = ["FUNCTIONRRIRAI",
              "RAIOONFRCCPWON",
              "PTCSNOBEUITOLO",
              "BNCACIANTOSLIH",
              "RBYOLILYNREFBT",
              "HYYNOGESTIBRIY",
              "AATTSIONCMCENP",
              "UORTENRRCBFVAU",
              "CEBEECVWIERORI",
              "PROCESSORTOPYF",
              "OHCOMPUTERHSOS",
              "YCYPRESREOSMRW",
              "OATHBRMVTHHCTR",
              "PGORWOOUIPSCHP"]
```

I need it in the formation of:

```
Puzzle = ["F","RU","PAN","BTIC",...]
```

so it appears that the word search has been rotated 45 degrees

any suggestions/help would be appreciated

Code for find_horizontal and words to find:

```
def load_words_to_find(file_name):
    word_list = []
    file = open(file_name, "r")
    for line in file.readlines():
        word_list.append(line)
    word_list = list(map(lambda s: s.strip(), word_list))
    return word_list


def find_horizontal(Puzzle, Words, ReplaceWith, Found):
    # Parameters :- List:Puzzle, List:Words, Character:ReplaceWith, List:Found
    # Return :- List:Outpuz, List:Found
    # Find all words which are horizontally in place (left to right and right to left), return the puzzle and list of found words
    rev = ''
    Outpuz = Puzzle

    for line in Puzzle:
        rev = line[::-1]

        for word in Words:

            if word in line:
                Found.append(word)
                Puzzle[Puzzle.index(line)] = line.replace(word, ReplaceWith * len(word))
            if word in rev:
                Found.append(word)
                Puzzle[Puzzle.index(line)] = line.replace(word[::-1], ReplaceWith * len(word))
            else:
                pass

    print("Found: ", Found)
    print(Outpuz)

    return Outpuz, Found


find_horizontal(Puzzle, load_words_to_find("words.txt"), ".", [])
```

Comment: I unfortunately have no code for this function of finding the diagonal words. im just looking for suggestions on how to approach the problem.  My plan is to rotate it in the way I have stated and then run my find_horizontal function i'll add the code for my find horizontal function.

Comment: On paper, start writing down the indices of the characters and look for a pattern you can exploit. ... `'F'` is `(0,0)`, `'R'` is `(1,0)` ...

Comment: @charlies You don't need to actually rotate the puzzle. What you want is a function that returns lists of indexes which can then be used to traverse the puzzle itself.

Answer (score 3):

Kind of silly, but you could insert string iterators to the front of a list, and then join and yield the next character from each iterator.

```
rows = [
    "FUNCTIONRRIRAI",
    "RAIOONFRCCPWON",
    "PTCSNOBEUITOLO",
    "BNCACIANTOSLIH",
    "RBYOLILYNREFBT",
    "HYYNOGESTIBRIY",
    "AATTSIONCMCENP",
    "UORTENRRCBFVAU",
    "CEBEECVWIERORI",
    "PROCESSORTOPYF",
    "OHCOMPUTERHSOS",
    "YCYPRESREOSMRW",
    "OATHBRMVTHHCTR",
    "PGORWOOUIPSCHP"
]

def get_next_diagonal(rows):

    iters = []
    for row in rows:
        iters.insert(0, iter(row))
        yield "".join(next(it, "") for it in iters)
    while iters[0].__length_hint__():
        yield "".join(next(it, "") for it in iters)

for diagonal in get_next_diagonal(rows):
    print(diagonal)
```

Output:

```
F
RU
PAN
BTIC
RNCOT
HBCSOI
AYYANNO
UAYOCOFN
COTNLIBRR
PERTOIAECR
ORBTSGLNUCI
YHOEEIEYTIPR
OCCCENOSNOTWA
PAYOECRNTRSOOI
GTPMSVRCIELLN
OHRPSWCMBFIO
RBEUOIBCRBH
WRSTREFEIT
OMRETRVNY
OVEROOAP
UTOHPRU
IHSSYI
PHMOF
SCRS
CTW
HR
P
```

Answer (score 2):

Apologies for the lack of efficiency, but here is my quick solution.

We view the grid as a set of coordinates. This solution is based off the fact that every item in the output you want will have X and Y coordinates than add up to a certain number. For example, the first item "F" has a location of (0,0), which sum to 0. The second two items "RU" are located ad (1,0) and (0,1), which both add up to 1. The third line "PAN" has letters located at (0,2), (1,1) and (2,0), and so on. Tracking this number with "i" in my solution, it needs to be big enough to scan down and across the lists, so this is twice the size of the length of the array. So we scan the list for items that are located at x and y coordinates where x+y==i.

Code:

```
Puzzle = ["FUNCTIONRRIRAI",
      "RAIOONFRCCPWON",
      "PTCSNOBEUITOLO",
      "BNCACIANTOSLIH",
      "RBYOLILYNREFBT",
      "HYYNOGESTIBRIY",
      "AATTSIONCMCENP",
      "UORTENRRCBFVAU",
      "CEBEECVWIERORI",
      "PROCESSORTOPYF",
      "OHCOMPUTERHSOS",
      "YCYPRESREOSMRW",
      "OATHBRMVTHHCTR",
      "PGORWOOUIPSCHP"]

output = []
i = 0
while i < len(Puzzle)*2:
    single_string = ""
    for y in range(0,len(Puzzle)):
        for x in range(0,len(Puzzle[0])):
            if (x + y) == i:
                single_string += Puzzle[x][y]
    if single_string != "":
        output.append(single_string)
    i += 1

print(output)
```

Outputs

```
['F',
 'RU',
 'PAN',
 'BTIC',
 'RNCOT',
 'HBCSOI',
 'AYYANNO',
 'UAYOCOFN',
 'COTNLIBRR',
 'PERTOIAECR',
 'ORBTSGLNUCI',
 'YHOEEIEYTIPR',
 'OCCCENOSNOTWA',
 'PAYOECRNTRSOOI',
 'GTPMSVRCIELLN',
 'OHRPSWCMBFIO',
 'RBEUOIBCRBH',
 'WRSTREFEIT',
 'OMRETRVNY',
 'OVEROOAP',
 'UTOHPRU',
 'IHSSYI',
 'PHMOF',
 'SCRS',
 'CTW',
 'HR',
 'P']
```

Hope this helps. Happy to clarify anything if needed

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, massively helped me. Fully works. How would this have to be edited to 'rotate' the other direction?

Comment: No worries! as @ekhumoro points out, it would be more efficient to figure out the list of exact coordinates you wanted and then only traverse the required items in that list, but for small scale problems this should work :)

Comment: If that program 'rotates' the list 45 degrees clockwise, could i repeat that function to turn it 6 times to make it appear that it has tilted the other way?

Comment: Not particularly. This solution is assuming that the shape is a square, so now that you are using a diamond it will have to be altered. However, changing the line `if (x + y) == i:` to `if (y - x)+i == 13:` should have the desired affect of rotating the initial square the other direction

Comment: Ahhh yeah that makes sense, my bad. If i cant rotate it all the way back around how would i 'rotate' the new list back to its original format ?

Comment: This is a little more difficult given the first solution i have provided. I would just keep a copy of the original list.

Comment: Ahhh right... i ask because in my program i have to replace the word that has been found with '+' then rotate it the other side to do the same

Answer (score 0):

Variation on a theme - generate diagonal indices.
If you trace your finger down the left edge, those are the starting point for the *top-half* diagonals and tracing your finger across the bottom edge are starting points for the *bottom-half* diagonals.

Top Half:
From each diagonal's starting point the first dimension's indices range from the starting point to zero (negative steps) and the second dimension's indices range from zero to a maximum of the length of the second dimension (positive steps).

Bottom Half:
From each diagonal's starting point the first dimension's indices range from the length of the first dimension minus one to a minimum of zero (negative steps) and the second dimension's indices range from the starting point to a the length of the second dimension (positive steps).

For both sets of diagonals you can take advantage of the fact that `zip` will *stop* when the shortest iterable is exhausted.

```
def cw(dims,ragged=False):
    '''Generate indices for diagonals based on dims.

       dims --> tuple: (nrows,ncolumns)

       Currently only implemented for all rows have same number of columns
       Diagonals as if the rectangle was rotated CW 45 degrees
       bottom-left to upper-right
    '''
    if ragged: raise NotImplementedError
    nrows,ncolumns = dims
    # top half
    index1 = range(0,ncolumns)
    for i in range(nrows):
        yield zip(range(i,-1,-1),index1)
    # bottom half
    index0 = range(nrows-1,-1,-1)
    for i in range(1,nrows):
        yield zip(index0,range(i,ncolumns))

new = []    
for diagonal in cw((len(Puzzle),len(Puzzle[0]))):
    new.append(''.join(Puzzle[j][k] for (j,k) in diagonal))
```

---

And a CCW rotation solution

```
def ccw(dims,ragged=False):
    '''Generate indices for diagonals based on dims.

       dims --> tuple: (nrows,ncolumns)

       Currently only implemented for all rows have same number of columns
       Diagonals as if the rectangle was rotated CCW 45 degrees
            top-left to bottom-right
    '''
    if ragged: raise NotImplementedError
    nrows,ncolumns = dims
    # top half
    index0 = range(0,nrows)
    for i in range(ncolumns,-1,-1):
        yield zip(index0,range(i,ncolumns))
    # bottom half
    index1 = range(0,ncolumns)
    for i in range(1,nrows):
        yield zip(range(i,nrows),index1,)
```

Answer (score 0):

I find it easier and clearer to just generate the indexes in two loops, down the rows starting at the first column and then along the columns starting at the last row:

```
puzzle = ['FUNCTIONRRIRAI',
 'RAIOONFRCCPWON',
 'PTCSNOBEUITOLO',
 'BNCACIANTOSLIH',
 'RBYOLILYNREFBT',
 'HYYNOGESTIBRIY',
 'AATTSIONCMCENP',
 'UORTENRRCBFVAU',
 'CEBEECVWIERORI',
 'PROCESSORTOPYF',
 'OHCOMPUTERHSOS',
 'YCYPRESREOSMRW',
 'OATHBRMVTHHCTR',
 'PGORWOOUIPSCHP']

nrows = len(puzzle)
ncols = len(puzzle[0])
output = []
for ir in range(nrows):
    row = []
    ic = 0
    jr = ir
    while jr >= 0:
        row.append(puzzle[jr][ic])   
        ic += 1
        jr -= 1
    output.append(''.join(row))
for ic in range(1, ncols):
    row = []
    ir = nrows - 1
    jc = ic
    while jc < ncols:
        row.append(puzzle[ir][jc])
        ir -= 1
        jc += 1
    output.append(''.join(row))

for row in output:
    print(row)
```

Output:

```
F
RU
PAN
BTIC
RNCOT
HBCSOI
AYYANNO
UAYOCOFN
COTNLIBRR
PERTOIAECR
ORBTSGLNUCI
YHOEEIEYTIPR
OCCCENOSNOTWA
PAYOECRNTRSOOI
GTPMSVRCIELLN
OHRPSWCMBFIO
RBEUOIBCRBH
WRSTREFEIT
OMRETRVNY
OVEROOAP
UTOHPRU
IHSSYI
PHMOF
SCRS
CTW
HR
P
```

Comment: My sentiments exactly.